# Return number of days between two dates, if DATE has a spicific format(NOT DATE)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, syntax-error

I develop specific software that uses Oracle10g Database.

This software have it's own DATE, TIME format in DB:
CurrentDate = number of days elapsed since 01.01.0001.
This number stored in DB as integer value, For example: current date is equal 735192.

I need to convert SYSDATE to this format. How to do this via Oracle?

I tried write some functions and SQL requst:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 

FUNCTION MyDaysBetween(aNow IN NUMBER,aThen IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;
IS BEGIN
 IF(aNow > aThen) THEN
    RETURN (aNow - aThen); 
      ELSE
    RETURN (aThen - aNow); 
  END IF;
END MyDaysBetween;


FUNCTION QAZ_SYSDATENOW() RETURN NUMBER; /*Converting SYSDATE(20.11.2013) to number of days since 01.01.0001*/
IS
BEGIN
 RETURN SELECT SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01.01.0001','DD.MM.YYYY') FROM DUAL; 
END MyDaysBetween;

SELECT * FROM TESTS T WHERE (MyDaysBetween(QAZ_SYSDATENOW(),T.D2) = 5); /*T.D2 contains 15.11.2013 asinteger number of days */
```

But something doesn't work, I can't find what is wrong.

Comment: I suggest to remove the parentheses after the SYSDATE.

Comment: I removed it, nothing changed. How to debug the script? How I can view what return functions at run-time?

Comment: Debugger (Oracle's SQLDeveloper IDE has one) or dbms_output package can be also useful to give you hint of what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm hardly a seer and I don't even have a glass ball or tea dregs and so I can't tell what you mean by 'But something doesn't work', however, your main problem is with the `QAZ_SYSDATENOW` function - you can't use `SELECT` like that in PL/SQL, you have to either `SELECT ... INTO`, or, in this situation, just `RETURN` the result of the subtraction. Check this out:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
FUNCTION MyDaysBetween(aNow IN NUMBER,aThen IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
IS BEGIN
 IF(aNow > aThen) THEN
    RETURN (aNow - aThen); 
      ELSE
    RETURN (aThen - aNow); 
  END IF;
END MyDaysBetween;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION QAZ_SYSDATENOW RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
 RETURN SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01.01.0001','DD.MM.YYYY');
END QAZ_SYSDATENOW;
/
```

I got rid of the `SELECT` in the `RETURN` and just return the value of the expression.

Test:

```
SELECT MyDaysBetween(TRUNC(QAZ_SYSDATENOW), T.D2) AS val
  FROM (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 5 - TO_DATE('01.01.0001','DD.MM.YYYY') d2
          FROM dual
  ) t
;
```

As you can see, I use your functions to calculate the days between today (`QAZ_SYSDATENOW`) and a day 5 days ago. I use `TRUNC` twice to get rid of the fractional part. If you need that, drop the `TRUNC`.

Output:

```
       VAL
----------
         5
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but: 1. Why SELECT? I need only result number for next IF operations in request with other Tests table fields. 2. What is "- 5 -" in your example?

Comment: @Alexandr The `SELECT` statement that I provided is merely a test of your function. You can use your functions however you want. My intention was to show you that it works. `-5` is just to get a date 5 days ago, just for a test, to subtract it later from `SYSDATE` to show that the function works.